# C segmentation fault with integer assignment

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the below code, and when I run it without the `int milli =` in line 20 (near the bottom), it runs just fine, however when I assign the result of the function to the variable (`milli`) it throws a segmentation fault. I can't see what the difference could be to cause a segfault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

// convert a timeval and time to milliseconds of today
int seconds_of_day(struct timeval *sec, struct tm *tim){
    long int milli_since_epoch = (sec->tv_sec * 1000)+(sec->tv_usec/100);
    return 0; // this is return 0 only for debugging
}

int main(){
    struct timeval *timeval_struct;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *tm_struct;

    gettimeofday(timeval_struct, NULL);
    time(&rawtime);
    tm_struct = gmtime(&rawtime);

    int milli = seconds_of_day(timeval_struct, tm_struct);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your issue is that timeval_struct is never assigned. You need to do like you did with `rawtime` so that it's on the stack, or manually `malloc` memory for it and `free` it at the end.

Comment: This is silly. Your `timeval_struct` pointer is not initialized.

Comment: You can't use the value of a variable until you assign it a value.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I will accept the answer in a minute.

Comment: This is why I like rust, Ben :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `timeval_struct` as a pointer, but no memory has been allocated to it.  So it's pointing to undefined memory that your program doesn't own.  It crashes when `seconds_of_day()` attempts to access the `timeval` struct.

You can fix this by declaring `timeval_struct` as an actual struct, rather than as a pointer:

```
int main() {
    struct timeval timeval_struct;  // Actual struct, not pointer.
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *tm_struct;

    gettimeofday(&timeval_struct, NULL);  // Pass address of struct.
    time(&rawtime);
    // This is OK: gmtime() returns a pointer to allocated memory.
    tm_struct = gmtime(&rawtime);

    // Pass address of allocated timeval_struct.
    // NOTE:  seconds_of_day() does not use tm_struct at all.
    int milli = seconds_of_day(&timeval_struct, tm_struct);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I saw the comments I implemented this solution and it worked, and for that you can get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Where does `timeval_struct` point to? You didn't allocate space for that.
Either use `malloc`, or declare a `struct timeval timeval_struct;` and pass its address to `gettimeofday(&timeval_struct, NULL)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked but I followed Adams answer as it was more comprehensive. I have still up-voted yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code crashes because `timeval_struct` pointer is uninitialized. You need to allocate a `struct timeval` to it, or use an automatic variable instead of a pointer, like this:

```
struct timeval timeval_struct;
...
gettimeofday(&timeval_struct, NULL);
...
int milli = seconds_of_day(&timeval_struct, tm_struct);
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ADfJu6).